# Unable to append the data to the div

Tags: jquery

I have been provided with this below css

```
<div class="Topping-details">
<img src="images/arrow-topping.png"/>
<section>
<i id="topping-close"></i>
<a href="#">Ketchup Extra - Rs. 25/-</a>
<a href="#" class="tpActive">Butter Extra - Rs. 25/-</a>
</section> 
</div>
```

I am trying to append data dynamically to the div 
This is my div to which i need to append the data (All the a href data is dynamic)

```
<div class="Topping-details id='+v_item_id+'></div>
```

I followed this way

```
[
    {
        "toppings": [
            "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML",
            "Honey with Carmel  10 ML"
        ]
    }
]

var toppings = toppingres[0].toppings;
var toppingcart = $('<img src="images/arrow-topping.png"/><section><i id="topping-close"></i>');
  for (var i = 0; i < toppingres[0].toppings.length; i++){
  toppingcart.append('<a href="#">'+toppingres[0].toppings[i]+'</a>');
  }
toppingcart.append('</section>');
$("#"+id_attr_val+"").append(toppingcart);
```

Could you please tell me why the data is not being appended to the div ??

Comment: what is `id_attr_val` ? Provide the full script or a fiddle

Comment: `"Topping-details id='" + v_item_id + "'>` instead of  `"Topping-details id='+v_item_id+'>`

Comment: The <div class="Topping-details id='+v_item_id+'></div> is also inside a for loop , so i am giving it an id ,based on the data recieveied  from database .

Comment: Why not use just `$(".Topping-details").append(toppingcart);` - a class selector?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy just for knowledge why to put `""` if it does or does not cause any problem?

Comment: @VivekParekh It is completely unnecessary to concatenate an empty string to it.. It is probably required when we want to convert a number into a string..! But here it is completely unnecessary..! :)

Comment: Oh. Great! I get it now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes in your code

1. Change `<div class="Topping-details id='+v_item_id+'></div>` to `<div class="Topping-details id='"+v_item_id+"'></div>`
2. Change `$("#"+id_attr_val+"")` to `$("#"+id_attr_val)`

Comment: can i target only div at this line $("#"+id_attr_val) , because the sam eid is being used for other elements also .

Comment: You can't use duplicate IDs. Use class selector instead - `$('.Topping-details')` or any other unique attribute.  Post all the code in your question including for loop.

Comment: The $('.Topping-details') has worked , but it is appending data to all the elements , so is it posssible to use any selector in this case ??

Comment: You need to have a unqiue attribute for that. like `$('.Topping-details[uniqueAttr="XYZ"]')`. I still suggest to change your ID allocating mechanism. It is the best solution here.